# Accessing consumer app configs when creating nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on creating a nuget package. When it is imported into a project I wish to check if a value has been added to that project's app config. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Where the value set in the config file is "SnakeCase"

```
    public bool DetermineIfSnakeCase()
    {
        var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        var file = Path.GetFileName(path);
        var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap
        {
            ExeConfigFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(directory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + file))
        };
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        return Convert.ToBoolean(config.AppSettings.Settings["SnakeCase"].Value);
    }
```